# Android SMS Intent not sending full message, other options?

Tags: android, string, sms

I'm sending an SMS from my app using an Intent. The SMS pulls a string with "\n" and "\t" formatting out of a text view to send out to a contact of the user's choosing.

**My problem** is that when sending from a device to another device, the SMS only sends the first 15 characters of the message! When the message appears on the first device, it has all the characters in the string. Then only the first 15 of those characters are received by the second device.

```
    // SMS Activity
     public void sendSMS(View v) { 
         mess = ""+Summary.getText().toString();
         Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:"); 
         Intent txt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri); 
         txt.putExtra("sms_body", mess); 
         startActivity(txt); 
   }
```

This is how I generated the string for the message. The text view is also being used for showing the string in the App.

```
   for(...){
   if{...}
   else{ 
       String beer = name[counter];
       int amount = amt[counter];
       inText += "x"+ amount+ "\t" + beer + "\n";
           }
           }
       Summary.setText(""+inText);
       mess = ""+Summary.getText().toString();
```

Is there a different method to go about sending this string through sms? I know I can do it using SmsManager, but I want to be able to use the phones messaging system (easier because they can choose the contacts). Any examples I can follow?

Could I use a cursor to get the information for the string?

Answer (score 0):

try adding `txt.setType("text/plain");`

this might solve your problem.

Comment: Adding that line caused a force close when the intent was called. I'm gonna keep looking into that though, thanks.